# Content Security Policy error while loading Iframe

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, iframe, content-security-policy

We are getting Content Security Policy error while loading an Iframe in our website.

The Iframe is loading a separate site in a virtual directory for our application. The application works fine when opened independently in a separate tab, but doesn't work in Iframe of parent site.

We tried adding a Meta tag  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />`  in the site Master page but it didn't work.

Also we added `X-Frame-Options` in IIS Http Response Header with Value "`ALLOW-FROM https://virtual directory Ip Name/`" but still no success.

The Issue is present in both IE and chrome.

Console Log in chrome :

[image: enter image description]

Error Screenshot :

[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a config entry as below:

```
`<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>`
```

default-src with 'self' indicates that loading content such as JavaScript, Images, CSS, Font's, AJAX requests, Frames, HTML5 Media from same origin. Likewise you can change the policy for the content in Iframe using child-src and mention the site you wish to load. If it is having same origin/domain u can use 'self'.

More details can be found [here](https://content-security-policy.com/)